# Find all the values of x such that the given series would converge.

Tags: calculus, power-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (5^n (x-9)^n) / (n+9)  $

So this is a homework question and we have unlimited tries to check our answer, however, the answer I got as well as my friend who has been helping me with my Calc hw got is considered wrong.

The result of the ratio test was $5(x-9)$

So I got $-9.2 < x < 9.2$ but this is wrong.

Where am I going wrong or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Checking $\;x=0\;$ would give you a hugely divergent series and thus you'd know there's some rather important mistake in your calculations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the $\;n$-th root test?

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{5^n(x-9)^n}{n+9}\right|}=\frac{5|x-9|}{\sqrt[n]{n+9}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}5|x-9|$$

and now

$$5|x-9|<1\iff -\frac15<x-9<\frac15\iff 9-\frac15<x<9+\frac15\iff$$

$$\frac{44}5=8.8<x<9.2=\frac{46}5$$

Now check end points:

$$x=\frac{44}5\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5^n\left(-\frac15\right)^n}{n+9}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+9}$$

and the last one is a Leibniz Series and thus converges.

Check now the other point (and get convinced there is **not** convergence there), and thus the original series converges for

$$8.8\le x<9.2$$